# Flutter Android app restarts and then crashes (sometimes)

Tags: android, flutter

I have Flutter Android app that crashes for some users and only sometimes.
Some affected devices:

- Xiaomi 11T (Android 11)
- Samsung A14 (Android13)

User presses some button in app. This makes async request to Android native using Flutter Platform Channel. In Android (java) app makes makes network request. Then platform channel sends response to Flutter and user should see another view. Instead, app crashes after few seconds.
From logs it seems that Flutter app is restarted:

```
08-22 15:57:31.237 I/flutter (13490): 2023-08-22 15:57:29.645 last line logged by app
08-22 15:57:31.336 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): ViewPostIme pointer 0
08-22 15:57:31.417 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): ViewPostIme pointer 1
08-22 15:57:31.472 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 0
08-22 15:57:31.540 D/InputTransport(13490): Input channel destroyed: 'ClientS', fd=283
08-22 15:57:31.771 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): handleAppVisibility mAppVisible = true visible = false
08-22 15:57:31.779 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5823285 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2273} of ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=true alpha=false hint=false mUseAlpha=false visible=true left=false top=false
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): 92418693 Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x1a25930
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = false t = 0xb40000764d5b4000 android.view.SurfaceView.performSurfaceTransaction:959 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1105 android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged:371
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): applyTransactionOnDraw: mRemoved = false isHardwareEnabled = true t = 0xb40000764d5b4000android.view.SurfaceView.applyTransactionOnVriDraw:2048 android.view.SurfaceView.performSurfaceTransaction:959 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1105 android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged:371 android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged:15932
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): surfaceDestroyed
08-22 15:57:31.780 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 1 #2 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5823285 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2273}
08-22 15:57:31.785 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): updateSurface: mVisible = false mSurface.isValid() = true
08-22 15:57:31.785 D/BLASTBufferQueue(13490): [SurfaceView[com.my.app.dev/com.my.app.MainActivity]@0#9](f:0,a:1) destructor()
08-22 15:57:31.785 D/BufferQueueConsumer(13490): [SurfaceView[com.my.app.dev/com.my.app.MainActivity]@0#9(BLAST Consumer)9](id:34b20000000e,api:0,p:-1,c:13490) disconnect
08-22 15:57:31.785 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.785 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb40000763ce36a00 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:1172 android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged:371
08-22 15:57:31.785 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.785 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb40000763ce36a00
08-22 15:57:31.786 V/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=1080 h=2273, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2273)
08-22 15:57:31.786 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): windowPositionLost, frameNr = 0
08-22 15:57:31.786 D/OpenGLRenderer(13490): setSurface called with nullptr
08-22 15:57:31.786 D/OpenGLRenderer(13490): setSurface() destroyed EGLSurface
08-22 15:57:31.786 D/OpenGLRenderer(13490): destroyEglSurface
08-22 15:57:31.787 D/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): performTraversals mFirst=false windowShouldResize=false viewVisibilityChanged=true mForceNextWindowRelayout=false params=null
08-22 15:57:31.791 D/BLASTBufferQueue(13490): [ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]#8](f:0,a:1) destructor()
08-22 15:57:31.791 D/BufferQueueConsumer(13490): [ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]#8(BLAST Consumer)8](id:34b20000000d,api:0,p:-1,c:13490) disconnect
08-22 15:57:31.792 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2408) new=(0,0,1080,2408) req=(1080,2408)8 dur=4 res=0x2 s={false 0x0} ch=true seqId=0
08-22 15:57:31.792 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): windowStopped(true) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{5823285 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,2273} of ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.792 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): updateSurface: surface is not valid
08-22 15:57:31.792 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.793 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb4000075b80de200 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:998 android.view.SurfaceView.setWindowStopped:335
08-22 15:57:31.793 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.793 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb4000075b80de200
08-22 15:57:31.793 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): updateSurface: surface is not valid
08-22 15:57:31.793 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.794 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb4000075b81a3100 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:998 android.view.SurfaceView.lambda$new$0$android-view-SurfaceView:200
08-22 15:57:31.794 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.794 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb4000075b81a3100
08-22 15:57:31.794 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): stopped(true) old = false
08-22 15:57:31.794 D/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): WindowStopped on com.my.app.dev/com.my.app.MainActivity set to true
08-22 15:57:31.795 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): updateSurface: surface is not valid
08-22 15:57:31.795 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.796 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb40000764d63b200 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:998 android.view.SurfaceView.setVisibility:392
08-22 15:57:31.796 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.796 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb40000764d63b200
08-22 15:57:31.797 I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(13490): removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@8cf0932[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.799 D/InputMethodManager(13490): startInputInner - Id : 0
08-22 15:57:31.799 I/InputMethodManager(13490): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
08-22 15:57:31.802 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490):  setAlpha: mUseAlpha = false alpha=0.0
08-22 15:57:31.802 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490):  updateSurfaceAlpha: setUseAlpha() is not called, ignored.
08-22 15:57:31.903 E/libEGL  (13490): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
08-22 15:57:31.914 D/libMEOW (13490): meow delete tls: 0xb4000075bba02f40
08-22 15:57:31.914 D/libMEOW (13490): meow delete tls: 0xb40000764e388280
08-22 15:57:31.916 D/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): updateSurface: surface is not valid
08-22 15:57:31.916 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb4000075b81a3500 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface:998 android.view.SurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow:496
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb4000075b81a3500
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): onDetachedFromWindow: tryReleaseSurfaces()
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): releaseSurfaces: viewRoot = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: vri = ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity] fRS = true t = 0xb400007649f70700 android.view.SurfaceView.releaseSurfaces:858 android.view.SurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow:500 android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow:22527
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/SurfaceView@5823285(13490): applyTransactionOnVriDraw: viewRoot.applyTransactionOnDrawFromReleaseSurfaces
08-22 15:57:31.917 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): from releaseSurfaces t.apply t = 0xb400007649f70700
08-22 15:57:31.919 I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(13490): removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@8cf0932[MainActivity]
08-22 15:57:31.919 D/OpenGLRenderer(13490): setSurface called with nullptr
08-22 15:57:31.919 I/ViewRootImpl@7d7df[MainActivity](13490): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
08-22 15:57:31.921 D/InputTransport(13490): Input channel destroyed: '8a96cbc', fd=120
08-22 15:57:33.255 D/libMEOW (13490): meow new tls: 0xb4000075bb676f80
08-22 15:57:33.255 D/libMEOW (13490): applied 2 plugins for [com.my.app.dev]:
08-22 15:57:33.255 D/libMEOW (13490):   plugin 1: [libMEOW_gift.so]:
08-22 15:57:33.255 D/libMEOW (13490):   plugin 2: [libMEOW_semaphore]:
08-22 15:57:33.258 D/BufferQueueConsumer(13490): [](id:34b20000000f,api:0,p:-1,c:13490) connect: controlledByApp=true
08-22 15:57:33.259 D/SharedPreferences:(13490): using custom resource name - com.my.app.dev_preferences
08-22 15:57:33.259 W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry(13490): Attempted to register plugin (o.setPages@ee2e190) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cb41a89).
...
08-22 15:57:33.260 W/FlutterEngineCxnRegstry(13490): Attempted to register plugin (io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin@49d9169) but it was already registered with this FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@cb41a89).
08-22 15:57:33.260 W/OnBackInvokedCallback(13490): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
08-22 15:57:33.260 W/OnBackInvokedCallback(13490): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
08-22 15:57:33.261 D/SurfaceView@99b17ee(13490):  setAlpha: mUseAlpha = false alpha=0.0
08-22 15:57:33.261 D/SurfaceView@99b17ee(13490):  updateSurfaceAlpha: setUseAlpha() is not called, ignored.
08-22 15:57:33.268 I/DecorView(13490): [INFO] isPopOver=false config=true
08-22 15:57:33.268 I/DecorView(13490): updateCaptionType: isFloating=false isApplication=true hasWindowDecorCaption=false this=DecorView@b510f7f[]
08-22 15:57:33.268 D/DecorView(13490): setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@b510f7f[]
08-22 15:57:33.268 I/DecorView(13490): getCurrentDensityDpi: from real metrics. densityDpi=450 msg=resources_loaded
08-22 15:57:33.268 I/DecorView(13490): setWindowBackground: isPopOver=false color=ffffffff d=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@7cbd795
08-22 15:57:33.270 I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(13490): check: return. pkg=com.stagnationlab.sk.dev parent=null callers=com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setVisibility:4401 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5468 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:54 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:176 
08-22 15:57:33.270 I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(13490): removeMultiSplitHandler: no exist. decor=DecorView@b510f7f[]
08-22 15:57:33.271 D/NativeCustomFrequencyManager(13490): [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::BpCustomFrequencyManager()
08-22 15:57:33.271 I/DecorView(13490): notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=false
08-22 15:57:33.273 I/flutter (13490): first line logged when app is started
```

After that, Flutter app tries to start normally, but some processes are still active (process id is still same). For example, following is logged multiple times (seems that obsolete platform channel from native to flutter is being used):

```
08-22 15:57:36.725 W/FlutterJNI(13490): Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: dev.flutter.pigeon.ServiceFlutterApi.onLogMessage. Response ID: 2371
```

And finally:

```
--------- beginning of crash
08-22 15:57:42.447 F/libc    (13490): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 14186 (3.ui), pid 13490 (my.app.dev)
08-22 15:57:42.451 E/FrameEvents(13490): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
08-22 15:57:42.476 E/FrameEvents(13490): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
08-22 15:57:42.492 E/DEBUG   (14233): failed to readlink /proc/14186/fd/88: No such file or directory
08-22 15:57:42.498 W/crash_dump64(14233): failed to attach to thread 13490, already traced by 13998 (com.my.app.dev)
08-22 15:57:42.498 E/crash_dump64(14233): failed to interrupt 13490 to detach: No such process
08-22 15:57:42.498 W/crash_dump64(14233): failed to ptrace interrupt thread 13490: No such process
...
08-22 15:57:42.508 W/crash_dump64(14233): failed to attach to thread 13996, already traced by 13998 (com.my.app.dev)
08-22 15:57:42.508 E/crash_dump64(14233): failed to interrupt 13996 to detach: No such process
08-22 15:57:42.508 W/crash_dump64(14233): failed to ptrace interrupt thread 13996: No such process
08-22 15:57:42.555 I/crash_dump64(14233): obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstoneProto
08-22 15:57:42.565 I/crash_dump64(14233): performing dump of process 13490 (target tid = 14186)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a14xmeea/a14xm:13/TP1A.220624.014/A146PXXU1AWB3:user/release-keys'
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Revision: '0'
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): ABI: 'arm64'
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Processor: '6'
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Timestamp: 2023-08-22 15:57:42.585278988+0300
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Process uptime: 278s
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Cmdline: com.my.app.dev
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): pid: 13490, tid: 14186, name: 3.ui  >>> com.my.app.dev <<<
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): uid: 10267
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000000000000000
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): Cause: null pointer dereference
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x0  b4000075bbb14a80  x1  00000075e20d4c98  x2  00000075e20d4ca8  x3  00000000002bb8f0
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x4  0000000000000002  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  000000757583f700
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x8  0000000000000001  x9  00000075e20d4cb0  x10 00000075df157f80  x11 00000075dbbed1c8
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x12 00000075e20d2e70  x13 000000000000001e  x14 0000000000000007  x15 0000000000000007
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x16 000000000000001e  x17 000000000000001e  x18 00000075c8e80000  x19 00000075e20d4ca8
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x20 00000075e20d4ca0  x21 b4000075bbb14a80  x22 b4000075bbb14ac8  x23 0000000000000001
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x24 0000000000013000  x25 00000075df22b000  x26 b40000764a1f5218  x27 0000000000000000
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     x28 b400007668ebcba8  x29 00000075df157958
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):     lr  00000075df022dac  sp  00000075e20d2e00  pc  00000075df03af9c  pst 0000000060001000
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233): backtrace:
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #00 pc 00000000007baf9c  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #01 pc 00000000007a2da8  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #02 pc 00000000007aaee8  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #03 pc 0000000000715934  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #04 pc 00000000007b994c  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #05 pc 00000000007bb70c  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #06 pc 00000000007beba4  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #07 pc 00000000007b7168  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #08 pc 0000000000838d98  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #09 pc 00000000005ce618  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.919 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #10 pc 000000000063d534  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.920 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #11 pc 00000000006285f4  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (BuildId: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6387)
08-22 15:57:42.920 F/DEBUG   (14233):       #12 pc 00000000002ea5a0  /data/app/~~7FaVcKZEGqBVzbSYOd0lSQ==/com.my.app.dev-nkTgnYwKWIH-ddcaFXPMqw==/lib/arm64/libapp.so (BuildId: c122fa82b016a62a)
```

Tried to symbolicate this crash according to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Crashes
App was built with Flutter 3.10.5, so used this symbol file: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/45f6e009110df4f34ec2cf99f63cf73b71b7a420/android-arm64-release/symbols.zip

Got something like this

```
λ android-ndk-r25c\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\llvm-addr2line.exe -e libflutter-3.10.5.so
0x00000000007baf9c
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/heap/marker.cc:426
0x00000000007a2da8
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/stack_frame.cc:0
0x00000000007aaee8
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/thread.cc:649libflutter-3.10.5.so
0x0000000000715934
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/isolate.cc:2730
0x00000000007b994c
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/heap/marker.cc:533
0x00000000007bb70c
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/heap/marker.cc:729
0x00000000007beba4
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/heap/marker.cc:1124
0x00000000007b7168
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/heap/heap.cc:551
0x0000000000838d98
/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/android_release_arm64/../../third_party/dart/runtime/vm/dart_api_impl.cc:4264
0x00000000005ce618
??:0
0x000000000063d534
??:0
0x00000000006285f4
??:0
```

One weird thing is that `file libflutter-3.10.5.so` gave this output:

```
libflutter-3.10.5.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd6386, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Last characters of BuildId do not match: e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd638**6** vs e2fafaed8116903d2d06f845b749b5e39ddd638**7**

Not sure, if the crash is important. Main issue seems the weird restart of the flutter app, after which app might be in the weird state where crashing is expected.

Currently out of ideas how to debug further. Any help appreciated.